# Promise is returning before Array.map. Why?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have two functions in my code; one is to get the names of Sitters and the other is to get the names of Children per Sitter.

The code I have put is a mock-up because, in the real world, I am tying it to a database that accepts the Sitter ID as a variable and returns a dataset of Children with the Sitter ID. These are, in essence, 1 database query for Sitters and one database query per Sitter.

The goal is to loop through the Sitters and call a function, passing in a Sitter ID, that would give me Children.

I want to add the Children to the iterated Sitter.

My problem is that the programme terminates once the Sitters have been acquired without populating each Sitter with children.

I thought using .map on my Sitters would cause the code to wait for the code that pulls the Children but it just resolves immediately.

I've tried all kinds of Async/Await and Promise combinations but I can't get it to iterate the Sitters, poll Children per Sitter and THEN return the Sitters variable with the Children populated.

```
const getSitters = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        const sitters = [{

            id: 1,

            displayName: 'Sitter 1'

        }, {

            id: 2,

            displayName: 'Sitter 2'

        }];

        resolve({

            result: 'ok',

            sitters: sitters

        });

    });

};

const getChildrenBySitter = (getChildrenBySitterRequest) => {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        const children = [{

            id: 1,

            displayName: `Child 1 for Sitter ${getChildrenBySitterRequest.sitterId}`

        }, {

            id: 2,

            displayName: `Child 2 for Sitter ${getChildrenBySitterRequest.sitterId}`

        }];

        resolve({

            result: 'ok',

            children: children

        });

    });

};

getSitters().then((getSittersResponse) => {

    return getSittersResponse;

}).catch((getSittersResponse) => {

    return getSittersResponse;

}).then((getSittersResponse) => {

    const sitters = getSittersResponse.sitters;

    sitters.map(sitter => {

        const getChildrenBySitterRequest = {

            sitterId: sitter.id

        };

        getChildrenBySitter(getChildrenBySitterRequest).then((getChildrenBySitterResponse) => {

            return getChildrenBySitterResponse;

        }).catch((getChildrenBySitterResponse) => {

            return getChildrenBySitterResponse;

        }).then((getChildrenBySitterResponse) => {

            const children = getChildrenBySitterResponse.children;

            sitter.children = children;

        });

    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(sitters));

});
```

I would like the Sitters object to be iterated and populated with Children for each Sitter.

As you can see, it returns the Sitter object before even populating it with Children and by then, the code is finished :(

Answer (score 1):

You must return the chained promise in your map function (1), wait for each of those promises to get fulfilled (2), and then log the sitters (3):

```
getSitters()
  .then(getSittersResponse => {
    return getSittersResponse;
  })
  .catch(getSittersResponse => {
    return getSittersResponse;
  })
  .then(getSittersResponse => {
    const sitters = getSittersResponse.sitters;

    Promise.all( // 2
      sitters.map(sitter => {
        const getChildrenBySitterRequest = {
          sitterId: sitter.id,
        };

        return getChildrenBySitter(getChildrenBySitterRequest) // 1
          .then(getChildrenBySitterResponse => {
            return getChildrenBySitterResponse;
          })
          .catch(getChildrenBySitterResponse => {
            return getChildrenBySitterResponse;
          })
          .then(getChildrenBySitterResponse => {
            const children = getChildrenBySitterResponse.children;

            sitter.children = children;
          });
      }),
    ).then(_ => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(sitters)); // 3
    });
  });
```

Output:

```
[{"id":1,"displayName":"Sitter 1","children":[{"id":1,"displayName":"Child 1 for Sitter 1"},{"id":2,"displayName":"Child 2 for Sitter 1"}]},{"id":2,"displayName":"Sitter 2","children":[{"id":1,"displayName":"Child 1 for Sitter 2"},{"id":2,"displayName":"Child 2 for Sitter 2"}]}]
```

---

You can also use async and await:

```
const main = async () => {
  let sittersResponse;

  try {
    sittersResponse = await getSitters();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
    return;
  }

  const {sitters} = sittersResponse;

  for (let i = 0; i < sitters.length; i += 1) {
    const sitter = sitters[i];

    let response;

    try {
      response = await getChildrenBySitter({
        sitterId: sitter.id,
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex);
      return;
    }

    sitter.children = response.children;
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(sitters));
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm only beginning to really understand some of these concepts but thought I had this one down. It works as expected now. Thank you so much for modifying my code so I can compare the two and see where I went wrong.